# Can PUT request change the URL?

Tags: api, rest, http, put

My application with a HTTP API provides some resources that are identified by name. So, the URLs are constructed as the following:

```
/path/to/resources/<name>
```

For example:

```
/path/to/resources/my_resource
```

The resources can be updated with PUT operations. It is also allowed to rename a resource with such an update.

```
PUT /path/to/resources/my_resource

{"name": "new_name", <other properties>}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No content
```

As a result, the updated resource is now accessible under a new URL:

```
GET /path/to/resources/new_name
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"name": "new_name", <other properties>}
```

The old URL is no longer valid:

```
GET /path/to/resources/my_resource
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not found
```

Is such behavior correct? Should the PUT operation return the `Location` header with a new URL? Is it OK to return the `Location` header with the `204 No content` status?

---

After writing this question I found another, quite similar: [REST API Design : Is it ok to change the resource identifier during a PUT call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091133/rest-api-design-is-it-ok-to-change-the-resource-identifier-during-a-put-call)
The accepted answer was that it is allowed, but not recommended. Still don't know what about the `Location` header, though.

Comment: There are no hard rules for what is allowed or not. Setting the `Location` header sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Sounds like a MOVE operation to me (RFC 4918).

Answer (score 4):

By changing a resource identifier, I understand you are *deleting a resource and creating a new one*. So, the approach you described in the question is basically a **delete** operation using the *wrong* HTTP verb.

According to the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the current reference for HTTP/1.1, `PUT` requests are used to create or replace a resource:

> [**4.3.4.  PUT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)
>
> The `PUT` method requests that the state of the target resource be
> **created** or **replaced** with the state defined by the representation
> enclosed in the request message payload.
>
> [...]
>
> If the target resource does not have a current representation and the
> `PUT` successfully creates one, then the origin server MUST inform the
> user agent by sending a `201` (Created) response.  If the target
> resource does have a current representation and that representation
> is successfully modified in accordance with the state of the enclosed
> representation, then the origin server MUST send either a `200` (OK) or
> a `204` (No Content) response to indicate successful completion of the
> request.
>
> [...]

I would do the following when the resource identifier needs to be changed:

- Perform a `DELETE` in the existing resource. The response would be a `204` indicating the request was fulfilled.
- Perform a `POST` or `PUT` to create the resource using the new identifier. The response would be a `201` indicating the resource was created. The response would contain a `Location` header indicating where the resource is located.
- To replace the state of the target resource (keeping the resource identifier), perform a `PUT` and return a `204` to indicate the operation succeeded.

---

I don't know about your requirements, but I wouldn't allow the user to change or create the identifier of a resource. I would **assume the resource identifier is immutable** and should be generated by the application (UUID, of example) or an identifier generated by the database.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Cássio Mazzochi Molin's answer. However the question is theoretical one, whether renaming the resource really changes the 'identity' of a resource.

For example if a person's name changes, that does not change who the person is. I still would like the `URI` I previously got for the "same" person to work, even after the name change.

So I guess my point is not to include non-identity related information into the `URI`. Include an `Id number` or similar content-unrelated information.

Don't do a `DELETE` and `PUT` to another `URI` (don't relocate the resource) if the identity of the object did not change.

Comment: Not exactly theoretical... This is a real case. Now I see that it was probably a bad idea to use names as identifiers.